# How center a css triangle vertically

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to know how to center the following triangle vertically on the red line:

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.triangle:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);

  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;

  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

The Problem is, that the element is centered but due to half of the element is "invisible" it doesn't look like that..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by changing this line:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
```

to this:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -20%) rotate(-45deg);
```

Comment: But why -20%? Any mathematical reason?

Comment: those percentages are for distance from original x and y axis.. you could use pixels as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to change the value for top, you currently have it set to 0. You can change it to something like top: 4;